# CorePlot 0.9: Anchor axis' and allow plot to move

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, core-plot

I am using `CorePlot 0.9` and it seems to be missing the `isFloatingAxis` property that others have mentioned online.  It is somehow not in 0.9?

I am wanting to anchor my axis' so they are always shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints system changed significantly in 0.9. See [my post](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/ef535a2b8374ad31#) on the Core Plot discussion board for details. There are also several examples in the Plot Gallery example app.